# Really next element with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie in Jquery, sorry for my silly question.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" value="2166"></td>
   <td class="sorting_1">2166</td>
   <td><span class="myparentid">743</span>
   </td><td>0</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to jump from 'mycheckbox' element to 'myparentid' element, ignoring the tree structure.
In Jquery, I tried something like :

```
var checkedRow = $(".mycheckbox");
var nextelem = checkedRow.next(".myparentid");
```

It does not work because next searches only in siblings...

Can you give me a hint ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is to go up to a common parent element (in this case the table row), then back down to the one you want:

```
$(".mycheckbox").closest("tr").find(".myparentid")
```

- https://api.jquery.com/closest/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/

---

**Edit:** To add some additional information:

```
$(".mycheckbox")
```

is the starting location, it's at:  tr>td>input.mycheckbox

(where `>` means directly below in the html tree)

`.closest` moves up the tree until it finds a matching parent element, so `.closest("tr")` will find

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
```

by looking at the direct parent "td", then it's direct parent "tr".

Normally I'd use a class here (`<tr class="businessobjectcontainer">`) (depending on what the business object is) then it can be a `div` or `tr` if you change this part of it later and seeing `.odd` I'd assume this is for styling and there'll be a `.even` - so that's not ideal as a selector.  So "tr" would have to do.

`.find()` does the opposite of `.closest` and goes down the tree looking for a matching element, in this case `.myparentid` will find:  tr>td>span.myparentid

which is what you're looking for.

`.find()` may not be the most efficient, but it's probably the most flexible as it means you can move the content of your `tr` around as much as you like.

A move efficient alternative might be to use:

```
$(">td>span.myparentid", $(".mycheckbox").closest("tr"))
```

but mostly it's just changing the syntax.

Comment: I do not think he want to search in `siblings` because _I does not work because next searches only in siblings..._

Comment: @GuruprasadRao not sure what you're saying... `.next` searches siblings only (and only after the current element) which is why this answer doesn't use `.next` and doesn't search siblings only

Comment: I mean the answer finds the same thing what `.next` does right. But the difference is you are coming from `parent` now. Not sure what OP is actually intending to find..

Comment: I am not sure this is going to work (but the error prevents me to go further).
`$(".mycheckbox")` get the first row
`.closest("tr")` get the second row
`.find(".myparentid")` get the child of this second row who has 'myparentid' class.
But 'myparentid' is in the third row and not the second !
(BTW, thanks a lot for answering my question)

Comment: Suprisingly, it works ! I need to investigate to understand the behavior of closest and find